# How to check user' group in django template

Tags: django-templates

I want to check user's group in django template and show the content based on user's group.

example: I have created two group in django admin as follows 1) management 2) staff.

when I m checking in template {{user.groups.get}} in management login its shows as management and also staff login its shows as staff.. everything is fine upto this..

when I am using if condition to check if user group is management and trying to show a content its not working..

```
{% if user.groups.get == "management" %}
  <p>Management</p>
{% endif %}
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let me answer myself to this question.

```
{% if request.user.groups.all.0.name == "staff" %}
    <div class="row">
        <h3> Permission Restricted to view this page<h3>
    </div>
{% endif %}

{% if request.user.groups.all.0.name == "management" %}
    <div class="row">
        management content comes here....
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

we can use request.user.groups.all.0.name to check user group name..